# xcode downloading files from webview

Tags: ios, download, uiwebview, nsurl

my question is , if i have uiwebview and i want to download file from any website when user click on download link i want to get the extension (file type) of this file without loading the url when he click on it so i can show him alert view to ask him if he want to download it.

for example there is URLs like this 
https://www.download.com/file=knwhuchuen

there is no extension on this url but when user click on it , it's show him mp4 or mp3 or zip file ?!

i'm using this code but it's not working good for me , is there any another way to do it

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked || navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeBackForward || navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted) {


        NSString *RequestURL     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",request.URL];

        NSURLSession *session    = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:RequestURL]completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error)
          {
              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                  if ([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread])
                  {
                      if (!error)
                      {
                          NSString *mime = [response MIMEType];
                          CFStringRef mimeType  = (__bridge CFStringRef)mime;
                          CFStringRef uti       = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, mimeType, NULL);
                          CFStringRef extension = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension);
                          NSString    *FileTybe = (__bridge NSString *)(extension);

                          NSLog(@"Type =  %@",FileTybe);
                      }else
                      {
                          UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                                                         message:@"internt issu"
                                                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                          UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"try again" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

                          }];
                          [alert addAction:defaultAction];
                          [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                      }
                  }
              });

          }]resume];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: define 'not working good for me'

Comment: because this code load the page then it's  show me the alert view

Comment: did you find a solution to this? If yes, then can you please post a proper solution, how did you fix this.